# UWP/XAML: Make TextBlock inside Grid automatically shrink

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a grid that contains a couple of TextBlocks:

```
 <Grid x:Name="TopToolBarTitleGrid"
          Grid.Row="1"
          Grid.Column="1"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Aid_MainPage_TextBlock_ViewTitle"
                   Grid.Row="0"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   FontSize="21" 
                   FontWeight="SemiBold" 
                   Foreground="{Binding ScreenLocked, Converter={StaticResource BooleanForegroundBrushDisabledConverter}}"
                   ManipulationCompleted="OnInfoTabManipulationCompleted" 
                   ManipulationDelta="OnInfoTabManipulationDelta"
                   ManipulationMode="TranslateY"
                   ManipulationStarted="OnInfoTabManipulationStarted"
                   Margin="0,0,5,0" 
                   Tapped="OnInfoTabTapped"
                   Text="{Binding ViewTitle}" 
                   TextAlignment="Right" 
                   TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" 
                   TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Visibility="{Binding ElementName=This, Path=Title, Converter={StaticResource NTVC}, ConverterParameter=-}"/>
        <TextBlock AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Aid_MainPage_TextBlock_SelectedFleetName"
                   Grid.Row="0"
                   Grid.Column="1"
                   FontSize="21" 
                   Foreground="{Binding ScreenLocked, Converter={StaticResource BooleanForegroundBrushDisabledConverter}}"
                   ManipulationCompleted="OnInfoTabManipulationCompleted" 
                   ManipulationDelta="OnInfoTabManipulationDelta"
                   ManipulationMode="TranslateY"
                   ManipulationStarted="OnInfoTabManipulationStarted"
                   Margin="5,0,0,0"
                   Tapped="OnInfoTabTapped"
                   Text="{Binding Path=TailoredEnrouteSelectedFleetInfo}"
                   TextAlignment="Left" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Visibility="{Binding Path=TailoredEnrouteFleetsAvailable, Converter={StaticResource BTVC}}" />

    </Grid>
```

Currently, this exhibits two undesirable properties:

1. When text is too long, it is truncated with an Ellipsis. (I see this behavior is specified by the TextTrimming property. Should I set it to "None" to get auto-shrinking behavior?)
2. When the grid becomes too narrow (by, say, narrowing the window), it clips the edges of the text instead of shrinking it.

I would like the text to shrink to fit when it grows too long, and also if the space narrows. It seems like there should be a simple way to do this, but my googling has so far turned up suggestions to use a Grid (already doing that) and a Viewbox (which in my tests did nothing).

I'm a baby when it comes to UWP development, I spend most of my time on iOS, so please forgive this dumb question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When text is too long, it is truncated with an Ellipsis. (I see this behavior is specified by the TextTrimming property. Should I set it to "None" to get auto-shrinking behavior?)

The [`TextTrimming`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.texttrimming) property uses to get or set the text trimming behavior to employ when content overflows the content area.

> `CharacterEllipsis`    Introduced in . Text is trimmed at a character boundary. An ellipsis (...) is drawn in place of remaining text.
>
> `Clip` 
>   Introduced in . Text is trimmed at a pixel level, visually clipping the excess glyphs.
>
> `None` 
>   Text is not trimmed.
>
> `WordEllipsis` 
>   Text is trimmed at a word boundary. An ellipsis (...) is drawn in place of remaining text.

If you set it `None`, the text will not be trimmed. And [`TextWrapping`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.textwrapping) is used to line break long word. However, It can be used to shrink the text. Currently, there is workaround that you could insert `Textblock` into `Viewbox`. `TextBolck` will scale the whole thing to fit the parent.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Viewbox Grid.Row="0" Stretch="Uniform"  Width="200" Height="50">
        <TextBlock  Text="I would like the text "   />
    </Viewbox>

    <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Stretch="Uniform"  Width="200" Height="50">
        <TextBlock  Text="I'm a baby when it comes to UWP development, ."   />
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, but this does not work for a TextBlock that is contained in a Grid. The Grid clips its children instead of shrinking them, so there is never any pressure on the ViewBox to resize.

Comment: I was wrapping the wrong thing in a view box. Your code shrinks the text because you set an explicit width/height on the box. I can't do that here, I need the width and height to be dynamically calculated. But wrapping the entire grid in a view box does the trick.